# Wired connection is fine on windows 8.1 but loads indefinitely on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, ubuntu-mate, routing

The wired connection on my Ubuntu Mate 16.04 was fine before but suddenly it can't connect to the network, looks like it's trying to find the ip or something, I've set it to DHCP.

The weird thing is, it works fine on any windows machine, I use the same cable and also set it to DHCP.

I use a Mikrotik router and then connected one of the interfaces to a cisco switch which is used to spread the connection to other devices. There is no setting on the cisco switch, but on the router I have set the hotspot on which means that without username and password or a bypassed mac address the device will not get any internet connection. A wireless router is also connected to one of the switch's ports and it's working just fine. Another weird thing is the wireless connection from that said Ubuntu device to that wireless router is also fine, that wireless router is set up as a wireless switch so there is no different routing process from there.

So basically from this cisco switch, all of the connected devices (PCs, switches, routers) work fine but all of the Ubuntu devices load indefinitely.

To summarize the weird things that are going on:

1. It worked fine before but suddenly it stopped working
2. Using the exact same cable, all of other devices but Ubuntu work
   fine.
3. Ubuntu wireless connection to that same network works just fine.

What might be causing this?

ifconfig result on ubuntu:

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:b2:06:2a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::8910:44b4:61f4:8b16/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:465044 (465.0 KB)  TX bytes:329578 (329.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:76636 (76.6 KB)  TX bytes:76636 (76.6 KB)
```

Comment: Make sure your Windows is completely shutdown and isn't in `fast boot mode` which might be holding on to hardware resources!

Comment: @George Have you read my post?

Comment: When trouble shooting you don't assume anything...

Comment: @George But the windows is completely fine though..